# ResumeThread not working in this special scenario

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

Platform: windows 64-bit

Language : c

I have  a main program which creates 2 threads

1. Background thread
2. Thread1

Thread1 is executing function1 (print name 100 times in a loop with sleep of 10min between each print). After printing for the first time, it is sleeping for 10min.

Now the Background thread will suspend Thread1 and change its context to execute function2 (GetThreadContext, change Rip, SetThreadContext) and resumes Thread1.

The logic of Function2 is to print numbers from 1 to 100.

Ideally, I am expecting Thread1 to run function2 immediately after getting resumed from the background thread... as Rip is pointing to function2 and not Sleep.

But thread1 is not running until the sleep of 10min elapses... Let me know if i am missing anything here.

I am stuck here from many days...

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Suspend/ResumeThread do not guarantee that any kernel functions that are running will be interrupted. I would recommend making your sleep into an alertable wait using [SleepEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to tell it to invoke your function of choice, rather than mucking about with thread contexts.

Comment: My requirement is .....at any given point of time there are n thread in my application...if any exception happens then I want to dump the call stack of that thread.....Currently i have a piece of code which uses Stackwalk API but this API is not Threadsafe...hence i am planning to move to RTLCaptureStackBackTrace and traverse the stack myself.

Comment: Interrupting the thread at a random point and forcing it to execute stack-dumping code is not really threadsafe either. There's nothing stopping the function from not keeping the frame pointer in a register, for exmaple. I would recommend using google's breakpad library or something to write minidumps instead of rolling your own, they've already solved all the hard problems for you.

Comment: Alternately, use MiniDumpWriteDump: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The suggestion of using APC to have a function called in another thread (as the question suggests!) is a good one whereas suspending/resuming threads and tampering with contexts is an extremely unwise move. Dumping a callstack in presence of exceptions is something that doesn't require suspending threads and tampering with their contexts either. The thread encountering an exception can just do this. You probably don't even need to call some special API (for example, under gcc, I use the compiler's builtins, MSVC likely has something similar).